# v-modal with a multi part variable

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to ask this, but I'm having trouble setting up a v-model that has multiple parts.

```
v-model="formInputs.input_ + inputType.id"
```

That would end up being this in the data:

```
data(){
    return {
        formInputs: {
            input_(its id here): ''
            //example input_5
        },
    }
},
```

Is it possible to chain values inside a v-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` instead of `.` as key accessor:

```
v-model="formInputs['input_' + inputType.id]"
```